# Placing parentheses around dates

Tags: bash

I have hundreds of films on my HD in a single directory that are labelled in the following manner:

```
Gold.2022.mkv
Oppenheimer.2023.Imax.mkv
Ted.2012.Unrated.mkv
Dr.Strangelove.1964.mkv
```

etc.

I want to get a bash script to automatically rename the files by removing anything after the date, except for the .mkv file extension, and any dot just before the date. Then finally to add parentheses around the date. So the above files as listed above come out as:

```
Gold (2022).mkv
Oppenheimer (2023).mkv
Ted (2012).mkv
Dr.Strangelove (1964).mkv
```

Not sure if it's even possible. Failing that how would I just place parentheses around the dates?

Comment: Do you have `Wonder Woman 1984` in your collection? How about `Fahrenheit 451`? Add examples like that or any other non-trivial cases to your sample input/output or you're likely to get solutions that won't work for them. It's always far easier to write code to match the strings you want to match than to not match similar strings you don't want to match.

Comment: Are there any strings other than `Unrated` that can come between the year and `.mkv`?

Comment: If in addition to `Ted.2012.Unrated.mkv` you also had `Ted.2012.mkv` in your collection then you'd get `Ted (2012).mkv` output twice according to the rules you've shown us so far. Is that desirable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77788008/1126841 raises the question: do you want to rename the files, or just generate a list of the new file names?

Comment: with the Perl version of rename you could do: `rename 's/.*\.\d{4}\.\K.*\././' *.mkv`. With pure bash: `for f in *.mkv; do [[ $f =~ .*\.[0-9]{4}\. ]] && mv -i "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH}mkv"; fi; done`

Comment: I'm sure I will have some filenames that don't play nice like 2001: A Space Odyssey.1968. There may be other things after the date and before the file extension such as directors cut or extended version etc.

Comment: or: `rename 's/.*\K\.(\d{4})\..*\./ ($1)./' *.mkv` / `for f in *.mkv; do [[ $f =~ (.*)\.([0-9]{4})\. ]] && echo mv -i "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} (${BASH_REMATCH[2]}).mkv"; done`

Comment: Filenames with parens in them !?.... You'lll be sorryyyyy (-; Parens are used in reg-ex, and shell context and make if more difficult to do anything else with your filenames. Use a different format, maybe `_2001_` ? (All IMHO). Good luck!

Comment: OK, so [then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77787952/placing-parentheses-around-dates#comment137133614_77787952) you can have file names with 4-digit numbers in other locations, file names with other strings before the `.mkv` and elsewhere in the name, etc. - if you don't [edit] your question to include them in your example and state how they should be handled then YMMV with getting a robust solution.

Comment: How should a script know that the first `.` in `Dr.Strangelove.1964.mkv` should remain in the output as `Dr.Strangelove (1964).mkv` while all `.`s before `.mkv` from the other input lines should get converted to blanks?

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s dotglob nullglob 

for file in *.mkv; do
    name=${file%.[12][90][0-9][0-9].*}
    [[ $name == "$file" ]] && continue
    tmp=${file#"$name".}
    date=${tmp%%.*}
    newfile="$name ($date).mkv"
    printf "%s %s %s %s '%s' '%s'\\n" mv -v -n -- "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

- `shopt -s ...` enables some Bash settings that are required by the code:

  - `dotglob` enables globs to match file names that begin with `.`.
  - `nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `name=${file%.[12][90][0-9][0-9].*}` and other string manipulations in the code.
- `[[ $name == "$file" ]] && continue` skips a file if its name does not contain a date.
- Remove the `printf "%s %s %s %s '%s' '%s'\\n"` if you are happy that the code will do what you want.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. Run out of time to run today, but will try it out tomorrow. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to use a regular expression with `sed`.

```
$ sed -E 's/^(.*)\.([0-9]{4}).*\.mkv$/\1 (\2).mkv/' films.txt
Gold (2022).mkv
Oppenheimer (2023).mkv
Ted (2012).mkv
Dr.Strangelove (1964).mkv
```

If you want to rename files in a folder, use `find`.

```
$ ls -1
Dr.Strangelove.1964.mkv
Gold.2022.mkv
Oppenheimer.2023.Imax.mkv
Ted.2012.Unrated.mkv
$ find . -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c 'mv -i "$0" "$(echo "$0" | sed -E "s/^(.*)\.([0-9]{4}).*\.mkv$/\1 (\2).mkv/")"' {} \;
$ ls -1
'Dr.Strangelove (1964).mkv'
'Gold (2022).mkv'
'Oppenheimer (2023).mkv'
'Ted (2012).mkv'
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I use that same sed string to rename the files?

Comment: Yes, just browse the file line by line and run `mv "$line" "$(echo $line | sed -E 's/^(.*)\.([0-9]{4}).*\.mkv$/\1 (\2).mkv/')"`. Or, *if your input file is safe* (namely, names do not contain backslashes or double quotes), you could do something like this: `sed -E 's/^(.*)\.([0-9]{4}).*\.mkv$/mv "\0" "\1 (\2).mkv"/' films.txt | bash`

Comment: OK so I have to create a txt file of the films directory, then use the mv "$line"... on the text file? Sorry. I did not state earlier that I wanted to rename the filenames in a single large folder of filenames.

Comment: Do not use [`"$(echo $line | sed ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77787952/placing-parentheses-around-dates#comment137133566_77788008) as it can/will corrupt various file names by exposing the file name to the shell for globbing, word splitting, etc. and matching on parts of the file name you did not want it to match on. With the direction you're going in you're also at high risk of overwriting one of your files with a different one.

Comment: @EdMorton If `$line` is quoted, it should be safe, no? `"$(echo "$line" | sed ...)"`

Comment: @Entropy1024 If you want to rename files in a folder, you should go with `find`.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard I think so. I thought the `sed` command could find 4 digits inside parens in some other part of the line than where you intended, but now I think it would match the last such string on the line which would be the one you want. It can still overwrite one file with another of course, e.g. an existing file or a newly generated file name with the same name as another generated file name.

Comment: Yes, it would match the last occurrence of 4 digits. There is indeed an overwriting risk, however this is inherent to the request. Could be mitigated with `--interactive` option of `mv` though.